# How to generate a PDF file and Upload to Blob Storage using R in machine learning studio notebooks

Tags: r, azure, pdf, azure-blob-storage

I have been able to open a connection to Azure Blog Storage, read a CSV file and show the results in Azure Machine Learning Studio, Notebooks.

What I want to achieve, is to generate a PDF file and Upload it to the blob container.

I used the documentation here to connect to Azure Storage:
https://github.com/cloudyr/AzureStor

```
install.packages("AzureStor")
library(AzureStor)
bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net", key="abc")
list_storage_containers(bl_endp_key)
cont <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, "csv")
list_storage_files(cont)
rawvec <- download_blob(cont, src="Claims reserving.csv", dest=NULL)
```

Then I need to generate the PDF file IN MEMORY and upload it.
Azure Machine Learning Studio does not allow to upload or store files that are not python or R scripts, so I need to generate the file in memory and upload it.

```
pdf("1.pdf")
dev.off()
```

I tried this:

```
upload_blob(cont, src=con, dest="1.pdf")
```

But got this error

Error in inherits(src, "connection"): object 'con' not found
Traceback:

```
1. upload_blob(cont, src = con, dest = "1.pdf")
2. upload_blob_internal(container, src, dest, type = type, blocksize = blocksize, 
 .     lease = lease)
3. inherits(src, "connection")
```

I tried this

```
plot_binary <- paste(readBin("3.pdf", what="raw", n=1e6), collapse="")
```

But got this error:

```
Warning message in file(con, "rb"):
“cannot open file '3.pdf': No such file or directory”
Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection
Traceback:

1. paste(readBin("3.pdf", what = "raw", n = 1e+06), collapse = "")
2. readBin("3.pdf", what = "raw", n = 1e+06)
3. file(con, "rb")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve using similar code. please take a look at screenshot
[image]

pdf stored in Azure "Files" in storage account

I didnt have any content in this example to create pdf, so my pdf is empty one created in account. you can also store in blob as shown in this example in the link

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AzureStor/versions/2.0.1/topics/storage_container
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AzureStor/versions/2.0.0/topics/list_blobs

[image]

```
install.packages("AzureStor")
library(AzureStor)

file_endpoint <- storage_endpoint("https://<storage_account>.file.core.windows.net/", key="xxxxx")


list_storage_containers(file_endpoint) 

cont <- storage_container(file_endpoint, "csv")

list_storage_files(cont, '')

rawvec <- download_blob(cont, src="test.csv", dest=NULL)

pdf("1.pdf")

dev.off()

storage_upload(cont, "1.pdf", "2.pdf")
```

Comment: amazing thanks, can you paste the code please so I dont have to type it in.